# Random numbers when using identity instead of sequential

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I am creating a table on an azure data warehouse (synapse). I need to add a surrogate key to my dimension table. I have created the table with idenity as below:

```
CREATE TABLE DimAccount
(
    AccountKey INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,AccountID CHAR
)
```

when I insert values, I am getting random numbers in the AccountKey such as

```
AccountKey
17
21
56
```

I want the AccountKey to be sequential starting at 1. Can someone please advise?

Answer (score 2):

Identity values are not guaranteed to have no gaps.  They are only guaranteed to be larger than previous numbers in the table.

There is no issue; `identity` is behaving as it should be.  The gaps are actually important for performance.  Any effort to generate gap-less numbers tends to require lots of additional locking and synchronization -- for little gain.  And then, the gaps just re-appear if you delete any rows or roll back transactions.

In SQL Server, you could use a sequence to get the results you want.  I don't think that option is available in SQL Azure.

Comment: You don't need a trigger to use a sequence object - a default constraint will do.